# Мне необходимо проверить разбор предложений по членам

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, определения, дополнение, обстоятельство

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли разобраны предложения.

"Множество пчёл, ос, шмелей дружно гудели в ветвях акации"
"В течение сотен лет на волжские просторы тянулись люди"
"Студенчество города принимало участие в восстановлении церкви"
"Прибыл тридцать один делегат"
"К семи часам пришли только трое гостей"
"Миллионы сияющих огней и раньше и после манили не одного меня своей близостью"

1.Множество пчёл,ос, шмелей-подл.,гудели-сказ.,дружно,в ветвях-обст.,акации-доп.2.Люди-подл.,тянулись-сказ.,в течение сотен лет,на просторы-обст.,волжские-опр.3.Студенчество-подл.,принимало участие-сказ.,города,в восстановлении церкви-доп.4.Тридцать один делегат-подл.,прибыл-сказ.5.Трое гостей-подл.,пришли-сказ.,к семи часам,только-обст.6.Миллионы-подл.,манили-сказ.,огней-доп.,сияющих-опр.,и раньше и после-обст.,не одного меня,близостью-доп.,своей-опр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.верно,но акации - двойная роль:(чего?)акации - доп., (в ветвях каких?) - акации -несогласов. определение.

2.верно.

3.(где? в чём?)в восстановлении церкви-доп. с оттенком обстоятельства места.

4.верно.

5.подлежащее - (кто пришёл?) только трое гостей (только - ограничительная частица, разбирается вместе с подлежащим, потому что к нему относится, самостоятельным членом предложения не является); к семи часам -обст.

6.Миллионы огней-подл. (счётный оборот),манили-сказ.,.,сияющих-опр.,и раньше и после-обст., меня,близостью-доп.,(меня какого?) не одного - определение, своей-опр.

Comment: В третьем предложении "в восстановлении церкви" можно выделить на письме не только как дополнение, но и как обстоятельство?

Comment: Да, принять участие (где? в чём?) в восстановлении - дополнение и обстоятельство; в восстановлении (чего? ) церкви - дополнение

Comment: Простите за навязчивость, но Вы не могли бы объяснить,почему  " и раньше и после"  пишется без запятой и является одним членом предложения? В тексте было именно так.

Comment: это тесное смысловое единство, как и тот и другой. 
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm(link is external) (параграф 87) 
87. Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами
3. Запятая не ставится внутри цельных выражений фразеологического характера, образованных двумя словами с противоположным значением, соединенными повторяющимся союзом и или ни, например: и день и ночь, и смех и горе, и стар и млад, и так и этак, и там и сям, и туда и сюда, ни бе ни ме, ни больше ни меньше, ни брат ни сват, ни взад ни вперед,